# Android: Select user to make a purchase in play store

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, subscription

How to select/promote to select a user which will be used to make a purchase in Google play store while buying in app products.

Or to be more specific, I have a user that bought subscription, how can I select against witch google play account I am doing a query to verify his subscription?

Comment: verify purchase as in check the play store?

Comment: @tyczj It does not allows you to make a verification based on email.

Comment: but is that what you want to do, check if the current user purchased whatever through play store?

Comment: @tyczj Yeah. The problem is that a single device may have multiple google accounts.

Comment: the current signed in user is the on that it will always query against

Comment: @tyczj Yep indeed! Now how can I switch the user? Or promote to switch the user

Comment: I dont think you can, the user must switch account themselves

Comment: @tyczj I am testing now the option to use Google sign in button. In some place I found a reference that Google+ account is used as your primary account on device.